# How do I increase the size of the text that is displayed in the console

Tags: python

I want to make my font size to change just for one line of code like `print("Hello World!")`'s  output Is bigger. Because I am trying to make a little console game, I want the title to be big. I am on Windows 10. My code

```
print("PENGUIN ADVENTURE")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print()` has no concept of "font" or "font size". This is a setting in the terminal window where you run the command. So one solution is to set the font size using the settings of your terminal window.

Rather than making the title big, you can make it bold or different colors using ANSI codes. See [How do I print colored text to the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-do-i-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal) for details on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the turtle library game. I will let you change the fonts and sizes.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

font1 = ('Arial', 24, 'bold')
font2 = ('Arial', 50, 'bold')

marker = Turtle(visible=False)
marker.penup()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("CHANGE FONT SIZE")
screen.setup(700, 700)

marker = Turtle(visible=False)
marker.penup()
marker.color('gray')
marker.goto(-275, 305)
marker.write("BIG", font=font1)

marker.goto(-150, 0)
marker.color('red')
marker.write("BIGGER", font=font2)

screen.onkey(screen.bye, "Escape")

screen.listen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: How does that comply with "**in the console**"?

Comment: it does not, it a possible approach to a different solution.

Comment: Fair enough, that's a valid solution ☺